# Ajax form submit refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using this ajax code to run actions on form submit

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ticketupdate_please_wait_box").hide();
$("#ticket_update").submit(function(e){
    $("#ticketupdate_please_wait_box").show();
    e.preventDefault();
    dataString=$("#ticket_update").serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "reviewtickets_history.php?seq=<?php echo $_GET["seq"]; ?>",
        cache: false,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(res){
            $("#ticketupdate_please_wait_box").hide();
            $('.overlay').fadeOut();
            if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1)
            {
                window.location.href = res.substr(8);
            }
            else
            {
                window.location.href = "/admin/helpdesk/reviewtickets.php?seq=<?php echo $_GET["seq"]; ?>#last";
            }
        }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

once the submit was successful i am using: `window.location.href` but because the page name is the same that it should be redirecting to and i am just adding the `#last` on the end, its just adding it and no refreshing the page

how can i make the page fully refresh and add #last on the end of the URL?

Comment: You can change the URL by adding a random bit to it: `my-url.php?_=23451272598&seq=...`. A timestamp will always be different so you can rely on it actually refreshing the page. Otherwise go with the `window.location.reload()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
window.location.href += "#last";
location.reload();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `location.reload()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.reload:

```
     if(res.indexOf("success")!=-1)
        {
            location.reload();
        }
```

If you want to override cache, add a `true` parameter: `location.reload(true);`

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

if you want to reload the same page with hash value then follow below steps

```
window.location.href += "#last";
location.reload();
```

thanks